# Jest does not recognize external typescript module

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs

I have some runtime importable module imports via AMD define. Everything is working as expected but I just cannot mock any runtime module inside the tests.

Error message without mocks: `Cannot find module 'MyModule' from ...`
I also get the same error message when I try to `jest.mock` the module. just the error happens inside the test file then.

```js
// globals.d.ts
declare module 'config' {
    const val: IConfig;
    export default val;
}
```

```js
// main.ts
/// <reference path="./globals.d.ts" />
import config from 'config';
[...]
```

```
// main.spec.ts
import { main } from "./main.ts"
[...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A module that is mocked with `jest.mock` is expected to exist. Non-existent mocked modules should be labeled as virtual:

```
jest.mock('MyModule', () => ..., {virtual: true});
```